# Is Azure Front Door PCI-DSS Compliant?

Tags: azure, security, pci-compliance, pci-dss, azure-front-door

Azue Front Door supports TLS versions 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2. Currently removing TLS versions 1.0, 1.1 from Azure Front Door is not supported.

PCI standards requires that protocols TLS 1.0, 1.1 can no longer be used for secure communications.

So can you advise if Azure Front Door PCI-DSS Compliant?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the PDF that you can download from [`here`](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Overview-of-Azure-c1be3942), the answer is yes. Azure Front Door service is PCI-DSS compliant (go to Appendix A in the PDF to see the compliance matrix).